# Can't change permission/ownership/group of external hard drive on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, external-hard-drive, permissions, mount, chmod

I have an external hard drive connected to my Linux box.  I wanted to setup a web server to access files on it, but the permission on all files and directories on the drive are `rwx` for the owner which is my local login, and the group is the `root` group.

I need the files readable by the apache user, I was trying to set all files to be `chmod a+rwx -R *`, but this doesn't do anything (gives no errors, just has no effect.)  I tried changing the group using `chgrp` to my user group, but that won't work either, it gives me errors that I lack permission even when I run all those commands as `sudo`!

What's up with this hard drive???  `sudo chmod a+rwx *` should work on anything, right?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check the filesystem type it's using first with `df -T`:

```
sys@p:~$ df -T
Filesystem    Type   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
ext3          ext3    19222656   1050948  17195164   6% /
tmpfs        tmpfs     1684988         0   1684988   0% /lib/init/rw
udev         tmpfs       10240        64     10176   1% /dev
tmpfs        tmpfs     1684988         0   1684988   0% /dev/shm
```

If it's mounted on `/mnt/external` for example you will see that in the far right column. You can see the filesystem type in the second column. If it's NTFS, you'll want [NTFS-3G](http://www.ntfs-3g.org/) (probably already installed, if not `sudo apt-get install ntfs-config` then `gksu ntfs-config`). Linux already has FAT support for read & write although **they do not support permissions**.

If you want an NTFS partition mounted with ownership applied to a specific user/group, specify it in the mount switches:

```
mount -o uid=username,gid=groupname /dev/sdc /path/to/mount
```

If you change to ext3 as suggested above, you can use `chown`:

```
chown -R user *
chown -R user .
```

Answer (score 4):

As Kim said, you'll only get Unix permissions and ownership on a Unix filesystem.  ext3 is a good candidate.

If you must use this drive without reformatting, you can do it with options to the `mount` command that specify the owner, group, and/or read/write permissions.  These options affect all files on the drive (see John T's answer for how to determine the FSTYPE):

```
# list files as owned by X, use numerical UID as found in /etc/passwd
$ mount -t <FSTYPE> -o uid=X /dev/?? /path/to/mount/point

# list files as owned by group Y, use numerical GID found in /etc/passwd
$ mount -t <FSTYPE> -o gid=Y /dev/?? /path/to/mount/point

# list files as accessible per umask 
#   (022 gives rwx permissions to owner, r-x permissions to everyone else)
$ mount -t <FSTYPE> -o umask=022 /dev/?? /path/to/mount/point

# combine all of the above:
$ mount -t <FSTYPE> -o uid=X,gid=Y,umask=022 /dev/?? /path/to/mount/point
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this and it worked:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda3 /media/windows1
sudo umount /dev/sda5 /media/windows2
```

and then

```
sudo mount -o rwx /dev/sda3 /media/windows1
sudo mount -o rwx /dev/sda5 /media/windows2
```

Note that I am Using Ubuntu 11.10 and `sda3` is my Windows `C:`, `sda5` is `G:`.

Answer (score 2):

So, I had a bit of a time, since I had backups from multiple machines on the same drive. I had to install hdfsplus utilities (hfsprogs), then mount the drive, and finally change ownership of the relevant folders using both the user and group name.

Note: you can list the mount points and devices by just typing `mount` at the terminal.

First:

```
sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
```

Then unmount your drive if it has already been mounted:

```
sudo umount /media/user/mount_point
```

(Re)Mount the drive using the following args:

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdb# /media/user/mount_point
```

Navigate to the directory containing the problem folders. Then do:

```
chmod -R your_user_group:your_user_name ./target_directory
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is the only one of the solutions that worked for me. Tried all of the others. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably formatted as FAT, which doesn't support file permissions. Use ext3 instead.