# OSX how to chmod a mounted AFP folder from NAS

Tags: macos, permissions, nas, smb, chmod

I have mounted a drive from my DLINK DNS 320 Nas onto my Mac Mini 10.9 via AFP.
One of the subfolders where I usually store photos (named '2013') is currently showing restricted access permissions, and wont let me copy any more photos onto it. All the other subfolders have mode 777 and allow read/write:

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 john  staff      568 Apr  6  2012 2010
drwxrwxrwx  1 john  staff      738 Apr  6  2012 2011
drwxrwxrwx  1 john  staff      636 Oct 10 10:11 2012
drwxr-xr-x  1 john  staff      466 Dec  2 11:00 2013
```

I tried to change the mode of the 2013 folder by doing:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /Volumes/Volume_1/photos/2013
```

but the operation was not permitted.  How can I make the 2013 folder writeable again?

Comment: Who is `john`? Is that your OS X account name? And how is the drive formatted?

Comment: Possibly related: [chown: changing ownership not permitted, even though running as root](http://superuser.com/questions/732190/chown-changing-ownership-not-permitted-even-though-running-as-root) and [Can't change permission/ownership/group of external hard drive on Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/57092/cant-change-permission-ownership-group-of-external-hard-drive-on-ubuntu).

Comment: How do you connect to your NAS? I ask, because you tagged your Question with `smb`

Comment: @George: Your bounty statement was : "This question has not received enough attention". As you don't react to answers, let me say this : This bounty has not received enough attention (from you).

Comment: @harrymc I'm not sure how you justify the charge that I don't react to answers... This is the only question of mine I have not followed up on, as I have not had time to fully test the proposed answers.  The bounty doesn't even expire for another day.

Comment: Finding the correct solution to the problem may take several iterations, so your take on the answers is vital for refining and improving. Too many posts in this forum remain without a validated solution because of missing feedback from the poster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Mounting NAS Volumes in Mac OS X the Right Way](https://blog.netnerds.net/2013/10/mounting-nas-volumes-in-mac-os-x-the-right-way/) :

> My original idea was to mount my NAS to a folder in `/Volumes`.  This
>   was problematic due to **weird permission issues** and automatic folder
>   removal after a reboot.  I finally realized that for better
>   integration into my normal workflow, I would be far better off
>   mounting the NAS to my home directory in `/Users/<account>/`.

The author of the article therefore added the following line to his `/etc/auto_afp` file :

```
/Users/brandon/GoFlex -fstype=afp  afp://brandon:[email protected]/brandon
```

Comment: and how does this will affect the situation that even sudo can't change permission.

Comment: @MarcoM.vonHagen: Only trying it out will tell.

Comment: Its the entry in the ACL of /Volumes which will make the difference   
    $: ls -la@e /Volumes
    total 8
    drwxrwxrwt@  4 root  admin   136 17 Jun 13:41 .
 com.apple.FinderInfo   32 
        0: group:everyone deny  add_file,add_subdirectory,directory_inherit,only_inherit

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command to manually mount the NAS drive into a subfolder of ~:

```
mount_afp afp://mynas.local/Volume_1 /Users/myname/NAS
```

Comment: even better; if I mount this way, then run `chmod` on the hidden directory, when I re-mount the volume in the normal way through Finder, the permissions are fixed