# chown: changing ownership not permitted, even though running as root

Tags: permissions, ftp, root, ownership, proftpd

I managed to configure my Raspberry Pi as an FTP server with ProFTPD. The only problem is, I can´t upload and rename files and Windows Explorer says:

> 350 File or directory exists,ready for destination name
>   550 Rename xyz permission denied

Now I´ve read I have to `chown` this folder to the FTP user, but this does not work.

I have tried:

```
sudo chown -R pi /var/www (my default pi account)
sudo chown -R piftp /var/www (the ftp account)

sudo su
chown -R root /var/www
```

All I´m getting is

> chown:changing ownership of ... : Operation not permitted

I already chmodded this directory to 777.

`/var/www` is mounted from a `vfat` volume on my external hard disc.  Looking at it with `ls -l` I see all files and folders have owner `root` and group `root` and all of these folders have permissions `drwxr-xr-x`.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What is the current owner of the folder?

Comment: The owner of www is pi

Comment: Are you able to sudo other commands that normally require it.  Its almost like the `root` doesn't even exist.

Comment: yes I am, I was also able to change the root password

Comment: What does `ls -l` give for the failing file or folder? And your *"All I'm getting is chown:changing ownership of ... : Operation not permitted"* applies to *all* files and folders, right? Or do some succeed? If some do succeed, is the file or folder that is failing any special? Like maybe that is a file that has been uploaded by Windows Explorer with some temporary name?

Comment: Which OS are you running on your Raspberry Pi? And what file system? (For that `/var/www` folder.) And maybe specifying the group is required in the `chown` command too?

Comment: ls -l gives me root root for all folders/files. if I´m root, im not getting the permission error. the rights of these folders are drwxr-xr-x. I´m running raspbian, the file system of my external hdd which is mounted in /var/www is vfat. No it´s no file or folder from windows explorer as the upload is not permitted :(

Comment: I've rolled back your edit; please note we're not a forum. (That's not different from Stack Overflow, which you've used a lot.) If you have additional questions, then post a new question for that. Of course, first search, as it might have been asked before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't change permission/ownership/group of external hard drive on Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/57092/cant-change-permission-ownership-group-of-external-hard-drive-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I am going to have to roll back this question myself also.  If you have resolved it yourself post an answer, don't post the solution in the question, thats not how this website works.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think VFAT supports the type of permissions you're trying to set. In such case, the permissions are set the same for all files, when mounting the disk. Something like:

```
sudo mount -t vfat -o uid=piftp,gid=piftp /dev/sda1 /var/www
```

See also [Can't change permission/ownership/group of external hard drive on Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/57092/cant-change-permission-ownership-group-of-external-hard-drive-on-ubuntu) here on Super User, or the external resource [Connect your Raspberry Pi to a USB hard disk](http://raspberrywebserver.com/serveradmin/connect-your-raspberry-pi-to-a-USB-hard-disk.html).

Comment: no effect at all, tried everything of those examples

Comment: Surely the output of `ls -l` must be different when you mount the drive like above, @Nachbar90?

Comment: the output for the mounted hdd is drwxr-xr-x 15 piftp piftp

Comment: Sounds like me that your *"chown: changing ownership not permitted"* has been answered then?

Comment: yes but not my real problem. The hdd is mounted as read only I think. The command for mounting it as rw is just giving me the mount infotable

Comment: See my comment to your question, about the rollback. And please read http://superuser.com/about Success!

Comment: Now I´m as wise as before. Still no chance to get my ftp working

Comment: Then just go ahead and ask another question about *that* (if it has not been asked before). Your own title for *this* question was *"chown: changing ownership not permitted"*. By now you know that this was related to using an external drive, and how to set the ownership for external drives, so make sure you add that information to any new question you ask. Don't ask [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) please. Success!

Answer (score 1):

OP wrote:

> I solved my ftp problem by mounting with `umask 0000`